# How do I dynamically generate code from a form input?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an application that allows us to book guests in discounted hotel rooms; the trick is that the guest can only go to certain places depending on the demographic they are in, age, marital status, income, time of year ect... currently all these rules are hard coded into my program but increasingly the people in charge of marketing ask me to change these taking up all my time. I would like to build an admin portal that allows them to configure rules using a dropdown menu taking the string returned by the dropdown and using a the function object to create a new function; however this does not seem to be working, my question is two fold, 1 what am I doing wrong? 2 is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

TL;DR: How do I create a function that returns true or false based on a variables defined in a form input

Here is the way I am compiling the strings:

```
 package(input: Rule) {
    const expandedProperties = input.properties.map((prop: Property) => {
      let loaded = prop.operator.split('$ANCHOR').join(prop.anchor);
      loaded = loaded.split('$COMPARE').join(prop.compare);
      loaded = loaded.split('$CHAIN').join(prop.chain);
      return loaded;
    });
    let builtProperty = '';
    expandedProperties.forEach(prop1 => {
      builtProperty += `
      ${prop1}`;
    });
    const finalRule = `const and = []
const or = []
${builtProperty}
const andIsTrue = and.indexOf(false) === -1;
const orIsTrue = or.indexOf(true) !== -1;
return andIsTrue || orIsTrue;
`;
    return function(Developer, guest) {
    };

  }
```

here are some example strings:
Operator

```
export var Operators = {
  equals: 'if ($ANCHOR === $COMPARE) {' +
    '$CHAIN.push(true)' +
    '} else {' +
    '$CHAIN.push(false)' +
    '}'
};
```

Comparison

```
export enum Weekdays {
  Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,
}

export const comparisons = {
  Monday: Weekdays.Monday,
  Tuesday: Weekdays.Tuesday,
  Wednesday: Weekdays.Wednesday,
  Thursday: Weekdays.Thursday,
  Friday: Weekdays.Friday,
  Saturday: Weekdays.Saturday
};
```

anchors

```
export var Anchors = {
  DeveloperName: `const developer: DeveloperInterface = arguments[0];
  const guest: Guest = arguments[1];
  return developer.meta;`,
  SelectedWeekday: 'Guest.Date'
};
```

chain

```
export var chains = {
  or: 'or'
};
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code but at first glance it seems to me that you want to utilize a technique known as "currying", which is essentially a function that returns a function, so instead of writing literal code you write a function that returns an appropriate function based on the initial input, read more here: https://javascript.info/currying-partials

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "allows them to configure rules using a dropdown menu". What's in this dropdown? How does selecting from a dropdown correspond to what's in your code sample?

Comment: what Is in the drop down is the object.keys of each of these objects, and the value is the value of the key in the object, so if I select equals in the operator dropdown it will give me   'if ($ANCHOR === $COMPARE) {' +
    '$CHAIN.push(true)' +
    '} else {' +
    '$CHAIN.push(false)' +
    '}'